# "Sending a redirect is forbidden after the response has been committed" in sendRedirect

Tags: jsp

```
if(insertLen==6)
      {
          nextpag="&whichpage=/jsp/dealer/callcentre/CareProcess.jsp"
          redirectpath += actionPath+nextpag;                 
          response.sendRedirect(redirectpath);
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          nextpag="&whichpage=/jsp/dealer/callcentre/complaintFeedBack.jsp";
          response.sendRedirect(redirectpath);
      }
```

Here When I execute the above, I got the following error :

```
Sending a redirect is forbidden after the response has been committed
```

May I know why this is happening?

Comment: I have added a quote on the end of `CareProcess.jsp` hope that was a copy/paste error.

Comment: You can't send any kind of response back before you do a redirect. You have probably done something with the `response` object before, but that is hard to see as that code is not part of your question.